# MODIFICAR PALABRAS EN PROPIEDAD TEXTO - VUE3

Tags: html, vue.js, vscode, vue3, props

> este es mi codigo en el componente home, que llama a ItemsServicios
> Solo quiero poder modificar dentro de texto: algunas palabras y no
> puedo porque en el script no me deja usar html. Tampoco puedo usar
> v-html.

````
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :item="item" :key="index" class="services_items" :style="{ backgroundColor: getColor(index) , color: getLetterColor(index), backgroundImage: `url(${item.imagenFondo})`}">   
  <ItemsServicios :titulo="item.titulo" :texto="item.texto"/>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const items = [
   {id: 1, titulo: 'LISTA DE PRECIOS', texto: 'Mira nuestra tabla de precios y compara.}
]```
   
 
 

     ```<template>
           <div>
             <h3 class="title_services" >{{ titulo }}</h3>
             <p class="text_services" >
               {{ texto }}
             </p>
           </div>
         </template>
         
       <script setup>
           const props = defineProps(['item','titulo','texto','color','imagen']);
         </script>
    ```
````

Comment: No es comprensible tu pregunta, ¿en tu script estás mostrando dos componentes?, qué necesitas exactamente, ¿modificar **texto** dentro del componente **ItemsServicio**?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo es que deseas modificar algunas palabras específicas dentro del texto en el componente Home, podrías utilizar un filtro personalizado o una función de procesamiento de texto para realizar dichos cambios. Aquí te doy un ejemplo de cómo podrías lograrlo:

Primero, en el componente Home, crea un método que reemplace las palabras específicas en el texto:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :item="item" :key="index" class="services_items" :style="{ backgroundColor: getColor(index), color: getLetterColor(index), backgroundImage: `url(${item.imagenFondo})`}">   
    <ItemsServicios :titulo="item.titulo" :texto="replaceWords(item.texto)"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import ItemsServicios from './ItemsServicios.vue';

const items = [
  { id: 1, titulo: 'LISTA DE PRECIOS', texto: 'Mira nuestra tabla de precios y compara.' }
];

const replaceWords = (texto) => {
  // Reemplaza las palabras específicas
  return texto.replace('tabla', 'nueva palabra');
};
</script>
```

Luego, en el componente ItemsServicios, puedes mantener el contenido sin cambios:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h3 class="title_services">{{ titulo }}</h3>
    <p class="text_services">
      {{ texto }}
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps(['item', 'titulo', 'texto', 'color', 'imagen']);
</script>
```

Con la función **replaceWords** en el componente **Home** reemplazaría la palabra "tabla" por otra. Puedes expandir este método para incluir más palabras según tus necesidades. Este enfoque te permite realizar modificaciones específicas en el texto sin necesidad de usar **v-html** y sin afectar la seguridad de la aplicación.

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo! Yo me refiero a modificar los estilos y agregar links, tal cual utilizaría un <span> en html, pero en el script no puedo.